# Prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+8b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+8c}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+8a}}\ge 1$ for $ab + bc + ca = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, holder-inequality, uvw

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3.$ Prove that$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+8b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+8c}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+8a}}\ge 1.$$
This problem is from a book.

This cyclic inequality becomes an equality at $a=b=c=1.$ I try to used some estimate which based on this point $(1,1,1)$.

By AM-GM$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+8b}}\ge 6\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+8b+9}, $$but$$\frac{1}{a+8b+9}+\frac{1}{b+8c+9}+\frac{1}{c+8a+9}\ge \frac{1}{6}$$ is already wrong at $a=\dfrac{\sqrt{30}}{50},b=5\sqrt{30},c=0.$

The following Cauchy-Schwarz also doesn't help here since $$\sqrt{a+8b}+\sqrt{b+8c}+\sqrt{c+8a}\le 9,$$ is doesn't hold when $a=\dfrac{\sqrt{30}}{50},b=5\sqrt{30},c=0.$ Even $(a+8b)(b+8c)(c+8a)\le 27$ leads wrong inequality with same counter example.

Now, I tried Holder$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+8b}}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}\left[(a+8b)(ma+nb+pc)^3\right]\ge \left[(m+n+p)(a+b+c)\right]^3,$$but it seems hard. I can not find any special $(m,n,p)$.

I think my Holder estimae is not good enough. Hope to see better ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a full citation where you saw it.  "from a book" is not sufficient -- which book? (please list the title and authors and edition)  which page/problem number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remarks*: Here is an alternative proof. The proof of (1) is not nice by hand.
(1) is true for all $b, c \in [0, 2]$. Hope to see a nice proof of (1).

WLOG, assume that $a = \max(a, b, c)$.

By AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+8b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+8c}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+8a}}
\ge \frac{6}{a + 8b + 9}
+ \frac{2}{\frac{b + 8c}{2c + 1} + 2c + 1} + \frac{6}{c + 8a + 9}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{6}{a + 8b + 9}
+ \frac{2}{\frac{b + 8c}{2c + 1} + 2c + 1} + \frac{6}{c + 8a + 9}
\ge 1.$$

Using $a = \frac{3 - bc}{b + c}$, after clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 f(b, c) &:= 224\,{b}^{3}{c}^{3}+164\,{b}^{2}{c}^{4}-28\,b{c}^{5}+56\,{b}^{4}c+393
 \,{b}^{3}{c}^{2}+225\,{b}^{2}{c}^{3}-68\,b{c}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -12\,{c}^{5}-24\,{b}^
 {4}-80\,{b}^{3}c-704\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-368\,b{c}^{3}+96\,{c}^{4}-45\,{b}
 ^{3} -861\,{b}^{2}c\\
 &\qquad -165\,b{c}^{2}+315\,{c}^{3}+300\,{b}^{2}+444\,bc-96
 \,{c}^{2}+333\,b-171\,c+72\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

From $a = \max(a, b, c)$ and $ab + bc + ca = 3$, we have
$b, c \le \sqrt 3 < 2$.

If $bc = 0$, it is easy to prove that (1) is true.

In the following, assume that $b, c > 0$.

Let $x = \frac{2}{b} - 1$ and $y = \frac{2}{c} - 1$. Then $x, y > 0$.
We have
\begin{align*}
 f(b, c) &= {\frac {6{x}^{2} \left( 12\,{y}^{5}+3\,{y}^{4}-172\,{y}^{3}+6\,{y}^{
    2}+736\,y+503 \right)  \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 1+x \right) ^{
    4} \left( 1+y \right) ^{5}}} \\[8pt]
   &\qquad +  {\frac {2x \left( 549\,{y}^{5}+2607\,{y}^{4}+3126\,{y}^{3}+3842\,{y}
     ^{2}+9509\,y+4687 \right)  \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 1+x
     \right) ^{4} \left( 1+y \right) ^{5}}}\\[8pt]
 &\qquad + {\frac {2 [g(x, y)]^2 + 2h(x, y)(y - 1)^2}{ \left( 1+x \right) ^{4} \left( 1+y \right) ^{5} \left( 
   2877\,{y}^{5}+12474\,{y}^{4}+8930\,{y}^{3}-8984\,{y}^{2}+3617\,y+4190
   \right) }}\\[6pt]
  &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 g(x, y) &:= 2877\,x{y}^{5}+12474\,x{y}^{4}+807\,{y}^{5}+8930\,x{y}^{3}+1330\,{y}^{
  4}-8984\,x{y}^{2}\\
 &\qquad -5706\,{y}^{3}+3617\,xy-14048\,{y}^{2}+4190\,x-6301\,
 y+814,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 h(x, y) &:= 1066320\,{y}^{8}+8911776\,{y}^{7}+24116192\,{y}^{6}+24094752\,{y}^{5} + 40308096\,{y}^{4}
 \\
 &\qquad +175656160\,{y}^{3}+304888864\,{y}^{2}+204549984\,y+
 44815664.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: (+1). The most interesting point is the first AM-GM step. Which did motivate you to use such specific AM-GM ?

Comment: @TATAbox Just experience or try linear function.

Comment: Is there a better constant than $8$ ? I mean $\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a+kb}}\ge \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1+k}}$ with same condition.

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, it seems the best $k\in (5, 6)$.

Comment: Maybe CAS helps to find best constant.

Answer (score 4):

The Contradiction method helps!

Indeed, let $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+8b}}<1$,$a=kx$, $b=ky$ and $c=kz$ such that $k>0$ and $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+8y}}=1.$$

Thus, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+8y}}<\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+8y}},$$ which gives $k>1$  and $$3=ab+ac+bc=k^2(xy+xz+yz)>xy+xz+yz,$$ which is a contradiction because we'll prove now that $$xy+xz+yz\geq3$$ for any positives $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+8y}}=1.$

Now, let $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+8y}}=\frac{p}{3},$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+8z}}=\frac{q}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z+8x}}=\frac{r}{3}.$

Thus, $$p+q+r=3,$$ $$x=\frac{\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{8}{q^2}+\frac{64}{r^2}}{57}\geq0,$$
$$y=\frac{\frac{1}{q^2}-\frac{8}{r^2}+\frac{64}{p^2}}{57}\geq0$$ and
$$z=\frac{\frac{1}{r^2}-\frac{8}{p^2}+\frac{64}{q^2}}{57}\geq0$$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{8}{q^2}+\frac{64}{r^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{q^2}-\frac{8}{r^2}+\frac{64}{p^2}\right)\geq3\cdot57^2$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}(65p^4q^2r^2-8p^4q^4)\geq171p^4q^4r^4,$$ which after substitution $p+q+r=3u$, $pq+pr+qr=3v^2$, $pqr=w^3$ gives
$$65(9u^2-6v^2)u^4w^6-8(18u^2w^6+12v^2w^6-108uv^4w^3+81v^8)u^4\geq171w^{12}$$ or $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=-19w^{12}+49u^6w^6-54u^2v^4w^6+96u^5v^4w^3-72u^4v^8.$$
But by Maclaurin: $$f'(w^3)=96u^5v^4+98u^6w^3-108u^2v^4w^3-76w^9>0,$$ which says that it's enough to prove $f(w^3)\geq0$ for the minimal value of $w^3$.

Now, $p$, $q$ and $r$ are positive roots  of the equation:
$$(t-p)(t-q)(t-r)=0$$ or
$$t^3-3ut^2+3v^2t-w^3=0$$ or $g(t)=w^3$, where $$g(t)=t^3-3ut^2+3v^2t.$$

Let $u=constant$ and $v=constant$ and we want to move $w^3$.

During this moving should be that the equation $g(t)=w^3$ has three positive roots.

But $$g'(t)=3t^2-6ut+3v^2=3(t-t_1)(t-t_2),$$ where $t_1=u-\sqrt{u^2-v^2}$ and $t_2=u+\sqrt{u^2-v^2},$ which says $t_{max}=t_1$ and $t_{min}=t_2$.

Also, we have: $g(0)=0$ and we can draw a graph of $g$, which intersects with a line $y=w^3$ in three points or maybe, if this line is a tangent line to the graph of $g$, so they have two common points.

We see that $w^3$ gets a minimal value, when $y=w^3$ is a tangent line to a graph of $g$ in the point $(t_2,g(t_2))$. Also, we need to check, what happens for  $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Id est, it's enough to prove $f(w^3)\geq0$ for equality case of two variables

(the case $w^3\rightarrow0^+$ is impossible because it should be $\sum\limits_{cyc}(65a^4b^2c^2-8a^4b^4)>0$).

Now, let $q=p$ and $r=3-2p$.

Thus, $$0<p<\frac{3}{2},$$ $$\frac{64}{(3-2p)^2}-\frac{7}{p^2}\geq0$$ and $$\frac{65}{p^2}-\frac{8}{(3-2p)^2}\geq0,$$ which gives
$$\frac{4\sqrt7-7}{6}\leq p\leq\frac{65-\sqrt{130}}{42}$$ and we need to prove that
$$130p^6(3-2p)^2+65p^4(3-2p)^4-8(p^8+2p^4(3-2p)^4)\geq171p^8(3-2p)^4$$ or
$$(p-1)^2(441-294p+277p^2+152p^3-1368p^4+1216p^5-304p^6)\geq0,$$ which is true for $\frac{4\sqrt7-7}{6}\leq p\leq\frac{65-\sqrt{130}}{42}$.

Comment: It is so amazing @Michael Rozenberg. Which did it motivate you think of this method?

Comment: @Ha Diep Xuan Holder does not help and we need to use another way. I tried to use a Contradiction method and it turned out.

Comment: Thank you. It is a beautiful solution.

Comment: May I ask you a problem which is not so relevant? I work to prove $f(p)\ge 0.$ I checked $f'(p)<0?$ How can I use uvw ?

Comment: @Ha Diep Xuan In this case it's enough to check one case only: two variables are equal. I hope you say about another problem.

Comment: Thank you. I read some problem which used uvw and I see we use your statement when $f'(p)\ge 0.$

Comment: In any case, I'll fix my post later. Thank you for your intrest!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think your answer is correct. You check the feasibility of "two variables are equal" after you apply uvw (not consider the three constraints).

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg (+1). Althouth I don't like uvw for olympiad-type inequalities, it is powerful. I also don't like Lagrange Multipliers or KKT conditions for olympiad-type inequalities.

Comment: Later I'll write a proof without words uvw

Comment: The inequality is very nice but hard for me. Both solution is new (+2)